# How to give Full Path name in avrdude command?

Tags: avrdude

I thought of using fully qualified absolute path name in avrdude command. But I am getting error "Invalid File Format"

I tried with following two options. But both of them does not work. Even I tried / instead of \ in path name.

1. avrdude –C"C:\Atmega\programmers\avrdude.conf" -cusbasp -p m16u2 -v -U flash:w:"C:\Atmega\Arduino\UNO Rev3\Arduino-COMBINED-dfu-usbserial-atmega16u2-Uno-Rev3.hex" -U lfuse:w:0xFF:m -U hfuse:w:0xD9:m -U efuse:w:0x05:m -U lock:w:0xCF:m
2. avrdude –CC:\Atmega\programmers\avrdude.conf -cusbasp -p m16u2 -v -U flash:w:C:\Atmega\Arduino\UNO Rev3\Arduino-COMBINED-dfu-usbserial-atmega16u2-Uno-Rev3.hex -U lfuse:w:0xFF:m -U hfuse:w:0xD9:m -U efuse:w:0x05:m -U lock:w:0xCF:m

Answer (score 4):

I have a similar issue. The solution is adding `:i` after flash address like the following: 
`avrdude.exe -p m32 -c usbasp -U flash:w:"C:\path to project\ouput.hex":i`

It's ensure that it's 'IntelHex' format.

Comment: Instead of using the `i` format which forces "IntelHex", use `a` for "automatic" and `avrdude` will use the file extension to detect the correct format. This is the default behavior. Note `avrdude`'s documentation says that a format must be specified if the path contains a colon (`:`).